# USB ports stop working at random times Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: usb, printing

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 on Asus Tuf. This question has been asked - last year, and I see no documented resolution. After a random period, USB ports fail, and lsusb no longer shows the device I am interested in, an Epson ES400 printer plugged into any usb port.A reboot brings it back to working.
let me add a bit of information. The upgrade to 20.04.3 was a new install over 18.10. I delayed upgrading until a few days ago, long after the repositories for 18 were closed. So a new install was required.using the ssd drive that had 18.10 on it. I suspect drivers were incompletely updated - it isn't just the usb port that loses its presence, but the network connections as well. A usb wireless dongle disconnected randomly and could only be re-connected after a power cycle. Now I've noticed that my Ethernet connection connection also randomly fails - – although the network tool says it is connected, i must disconnect and then reconnect to get it working again. This is a workstation not a laptop, but i turned off power management, and never let the screen go to black. My suspicion is corrupted drivers. Any idea how to clean them up? –
no - no live CD yet.I'll get to that late tomorrow or Wednesday
Bert Berlin
1 min ago   Edit

Comment: Can you make a live CD (write the Ubuntu Desktop ISO to a flash drive [using balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), boot to it, and press Try Ubuntu)? Try to reproduce the issue in the live CD, and when you're done, shut down the live CD, unplug the flash drive, and when you turn your PC on, normal Ubuntu will be back. Please [edit] your question with if it happens in a live CD

Comment: although the network tool says it is connected, i must disconnect and then reconnect to get it working again. This is a workstation not a laptop, but i turned off power management, and never let the screen go to black.  My suspicion is corrupted drivers.  Any idea how to clean them up?